# When calling eth_getLogs, should I worry if a block is mined?

Tags: security

I call eth_getLogs to store some data in the database. In https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getLogs it says:

`fromBlock: QUANTITY|TAG - (optional, default: "latest") Integer block number, or "latest" for the last mined block or "pending", "earliest" for not yet mined transactions.`

So should I be worried that not yet mined transactions can be reverted?

Comment: Yes, better to use latest.. *one* of the problems which I guess could happens -> transactions in pending and earliest could be removed if the block didn't success and come in later in another block so u get data twice

Comment: @MajdTL What if I want to see all mined transactions?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? And why would u don that?.. if you want to see all mined transaction in the Blockchain then u need to wait and watch for every confirmed block (that could not be reverted, usually with 3-5 blocks delay) and then extract the transactions from it.. that require resources and not a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase you're looking for is "finality" - see pieces like https://hackmd.io/@prysmaticlabs/finality for a discussion of the topic, and be aware that older proof-of-work papers are probably outdated.

The short answer is that there is no short answer.

One practical answer is to just copy bigger players in the space.  As of Feb 13 2023, Coinbase delays 14 blocks before they consider an ethereum transaction final:
https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/getting-started/crypto-education/glossary/confirmations

[image]